Is it possible to 'extend' $dF_p$ for contravariant tensors as follows?
From Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds page 319-20:

Just like covector fields, covariant tensor fields can be pulled back by a smooth map to yield tensor fields on the domain. (This construction works only for covariant tensor fields, which is one reason why we focus most of our attention on the covariant case.)
Suppose $F:M\to N$ is a smooth map. For any point $p\in M$ and any $k$-tensor $\alpha\in T^k(T^*_{F(p)}N)$, we define a tensor $dF_p^*(\alpha)\in T^k(T_p^*M)$, called the pointwise pullback of $\alpha$ by $F$ at $p$, by
$$dF_p^*(\alpha)(v_1,\ldots,v_k) = \alpha(dF_p(v_1),\ldots,dF_p(v_k))$$
for any $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in T_pM$.

It seems to me that, similar to how the above generalizes the pullback of a covector, there is a generalization of the differential of a vector to contravariant tensors:
Definition (?): for any point $p\in M$ and any $\Omega\in T^l(T_pM)$, we define a tensor $dF_p^{**}(\Omega)\in T^l(T_pM)$ by
$$dF_p^{**}(\Omega)(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_l) = \Omega(dF_p^*(\omega_1),\ldots,dF_p^*(\omega_l))$$
for $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_l\in T^*_pM$.
There is some symmetry here, as $dF_p^{**}$ generalizes the differential by means of $dF_p^*$, and $dF_p^*$ generalizes the pullback by means of $dF_p$. What I meant when I said this new definition generalizes the usual differential $dF_p$ is that the following diagram commutes (keeping in mind that $V^{**}$ is usually identified with $V$):$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_pM @>dF_p>> T_{F(p)}N\\
@V ** V V= @VV ** V\\
T_p^{**}M @>>dF_p^{**}> T_{F(p)}^{**}N
\end{CD}
where $**$ is to signifity the map $v\mapsto v^{**}$ where $v^{**}(\omega) = \omega(v)$:
$$dF^{**}\circ v^{**}\circ \omega = v^{**}\circ dF^*\circ \omega = dF^*\circ\omega\circ v = \omega\circ dF\circ v = (dF\circ v)^{**}\circ\omega.$$
It becomes somewhat elegant to write elements of $V^{*^r}$ as $v^{*^r}$, as then $dF^{*^r}$ must always have a $v^{*^r}$ as argument.

Is my definition above well-defined? If it isn't, where am I missing something? If it is, does it have a name and why did Lee not include it?

Actually, I think this works even if we start with an arbitrary linear map $L:V\to W$, as opposed to $dF_p$.
